# retirar fundo do google chart

Tags: jquery, css, google-charts

Colegas.

Estou usando o Google Chart em um projeto, só que ao instalar ele nesse projeto, ele sobrepõe a div onde se encontra. Como eu faria para colocar transparente o fundo do Chart?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Coloca `backgroundColor: 'transparent'` dentro das `options` do gráfico.

```js
      google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
      function drawChart() {

        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['Tarefas', 'Avaliações'],
          ['Português', 11],
          ['Matematica', 2],
          ['Física', 2],
          ['Inglês', 2],
          ['Geografia',    7]
        ]);

        var options = {
          title: 'Avaliações por matérias',
          backgroundColor: 'transparent',
        };

        var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('piechart'));

        chart.draw(data, options);
      }
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
       <div id="piechart" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
```

Comment: Obrigado TaisBevalle. Funcionou!